# search in node-with-comments plus in unpublished nodes

Tags: search, comments

I need on my site a search. It should index the comments too, fulltext index is fine, they could be seen as part of body.

But as I use workbench with many steps, most nodes are unpublished. And I guess that ist not possible with builtin search.

So I checked search_api and it works for all content and its fields but NOT the comments.

Any suggestions what I could try?

Comment: [According to this](https://drupal.org/comment/765774#comment-765774) Comments are automatically indexed and for search purposes are considered part of the node to which they are attached.

Comment: but only in published nodes afaik...

Comment: Arr - of course, got ya. But won't most nodes that have comments already be published?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the search_api (plus search_api_db) sufficient. I use the search_api_views also FYI

in node index -> fields I add at the bottom another relationship and Comment->body extra

AND of course in the filter: Do not check "exclude unpublished nodes".

Answer (score 1):

You can use 
[hook_searchapi_entity_property_info_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!entity!entity.api.php/function/hook_entity_property_info_alter/7):

```
function mymodule_searchapi_entity_property_info_alter(&$info) {
    if (isset($info['node']['bundles'])) {
        // For each content type.
        foreach ($info['node']['bundles'] as $bundle_type => $bundle) {
                $info['node']['bundles'][$bundle_type]['properties']['comments'] = array(
                    'label' => 'node comments',
                    'description' => 'the comments of the node',
                    'type' => 'text', // or whatever you want here
                    'getter callback' => 'mymodule_searchapi_get_whatever', // name me whatever you want

                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and your callback

```
function mymodule_searchapi_get_whatever($entity, $options, $name, $entity_type, &$info) {
    // return the comments here, as you have everything in the function variables - i.e. use return.
}
```

Look at example implemntations of this hook and it should be enough to get your started.

Comment: I am not ready with this issue yet... hopefully I can try your suggestion soon.

Answer (score 0):

Have you worked before https://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations  module.. If not just try it. it  provides to create custom filter based on various relation in a format of view where you can add all types of filter from admin/backend.

Just try it.